# Is there a way to upload a file in React Dropzone with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, puppeteer, dropzone.js

I tried a few suggestions online but none worked.
Currently I'm trying this:

```
  await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/');
  await page.waitForSelector('input[type=file]');
  const fileInput  = await page.$('input[type=file]');
  await fileInput.uploadFile("file.png");
```

This doesn't work (or do anything).
Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the dropzone needs a little push. You could trigger a `change` so the dropzone knows that there is a new file in the file input.

```js
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    ignoreDefaultArgs: true
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://react-dropzone.js.org/');
  await page.waitForSelector('input[type=file]');
  const fileInput  = await page.$('#rsg-root > div > main > section > section:nth-child(3) > section > section:nth-child(1) > article > div:nth-child(2) > div.rsg--preview-60 > div > section > div > input[type=file]');
  await fileInput.uploadFile("./test/playground.js");

  ///HERE
  await fileInput.evaluate(upload => upload.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true })));
  ///

  await page.close();
})();
```

Comment: This works! My initial thought was to trigger a change on the file input but I guess I did it wrong. Thanks!